# How I can change the label format on echarts4r bar?

Tags: r, echarts4r

Hi and thanks for reading me
I am working on a simple bar chart in Echarts4r and I would like to label the bars with the value, but include commas in large numbers. So far I have not found a solution for this, does anyone have any ideas how I could do this?

My code is the following:

```
library(echarts4r)
iris |> 
  group_by(Species) |> 
  summarise(total = sum(Sepal.Length)*1000) |> 
  e_charts(Species) |> 
  e_bar(total,
        label = list(
          show = TRUE,
          rotate = 90,
          verticalAlign = "middle",
          textStyle = list(fontFamily = "Roboto Condensed", 
                           fontSize = 15)
           ), name = " Valor"
        )
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript treats `250,300` as two numbers, therefore it is not appropriate for echarts.

- We could try formatter to change the display of value, the input should be number in the form of `250300`.
- See here:
  https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/10854
- Also here:  Control decimal and big numbers marks #53
  https://github.com/JohnCoene/echarts4r/issues/53